# Configuration to set coredump_filter

Tags: core-dump

Do we have any configuration to set the coredump_filter value for a process.  I am aware that we can do it by modifying /proc/PID/coredump_filter.  But I want this to be a configuration so that we don't need to find the pid and set it every time the process is starting.

Comment: Who are "we"? Which distro you are talking about? Which process you are talking about? Could you please provide more details in your question?

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#CoredumpFilter= - this may be useful for those who use systemd services.

Comment: You may be looking for this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523279/coredump-filter-for-all-processes/36524362#36524362 .